# Why do I get "NoSuchWindowError" error with "getWindowHandle" when it should return the current window handle?

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver

In selenium 2 [getWindowHandle](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/javascript/source/lib/webdriver/webdriver.js.src.html) says:

> Schedules a command to retrieve they current window handle.

But when I try to do something with the handle returned from this it throws me the "NoSuchWindowError". How is this even possible? If is the current window it should not be closed. If is closed then the current window is another one. Right?

**Using:**

- Webdriver for javascript/node.js;
- ChromeDriver;

**Update 2:**

Seems like a [bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=339). The window that closes is the facebook login.

Here is how to reproduce:

- Go to some page that requests facebook login;
- A facebook login popup window appears;
- You login;
- The facebook window closes;
- Now if you try to get the current handle, then you get this error.

**As asked:**

I want to get the window title or similar, doesn't really matter, I just need the handle id.

Here is the full error stack, which is not that useful:

```
[8.572][SEVERE]: Unable to receive message from renderer
FF

(::) failed steps (::)

NoSuchWindowError: no such window: target window already closed
  at Object.Future.wait (c:\app\node_modules\fibers\future.js:398:15)
  at [object Object]._.extend.update (c:\app\tests\shared\Browser.js:183:62)
  at [object Object].<anonymous> (c:\app\tests\shared\Browser.js:138:18)
  at c:\app\node_modules\fibers\future.js:416:21

    - - - - -
from unknown error: web view not found
  (Session info: chrome=40.0.2214.111)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.9.248315,platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86)
    at new bot.Error (c:\app\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\atoms\error.js:113:18)
    at Object.bot.response.checkResponse (c:\app\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\atoms\response.js:106:9)
    at c:\app\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\webdriver.js:362:20
    at c:\app\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\base.js:1582:15
    at [object Object].webdriver.promise.ControlFlow.runInNewFrame_ (c:\app\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:1654:20)
    at notify (c:\app\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:465:12)
    at notifyAll (c:\app\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:442:7)
    at resolve (c:\app\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:420:7)
    at [object Object].fulfill (c:\app\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:535:5)
    at c:\app\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:1520:10
    at c:\app\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\base.js:1582:15
    at [object Object].webdriver.promise.ControlFlow.runInNewFrame_ (c:\app\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:1654:20)
    at notify (c:\app\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:465:12)
    at notifyAll (c:\app\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:442:7)
    at resolve (c:\app\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:420:7)
    at fulfill (c:\app\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:535:5)
    at c:\app\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\base.js:1582:15
    at [object Object].webdriver.promise.ControlFlow.runInNewFrame_ (c:\app\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:1654:20)
    at notify (c:\app\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:465:12)
    at notifyAll (c:\app\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:442:7)
    at resolve (c:\app\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:420:7)
    at [object Object].fulfill (c:\app\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:535:5)
    at c:\app\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:721:49
    at c:\app\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\http\http.js:96:5
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (c:\app\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\http\index.js:131:7)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at _stream_readable.js:943:16
    at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:463:13)
==== async task ====
WebDriver.getWindowHandle()
    at [object Object].webdriver.WebDriver.schedule (c:\app\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\webdriver.js:345:15)
    at [object Object].webdriver.WebDriver.getWindowHandle (c:\app\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\webdriver.js:672:15)
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (c:\app\tests\shared\Browser.js:23:12)
    at [object Object].fn [as f_getWindowHandle] (c:\app\node_modules\fibers\future.js:89:26)
    at [object Object]._.extend.update (c:\app\tests\shared\Browser.js:183:42)
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (c:\app\tests\shared\Browser.js:138:18)
    at c:\app\node_modules\fibers\future.js:416:21
```

Comment: Give an example of what are you trying to do with a handle and an error traceback. Thanks.

Comment: I just updated the question (: I thank you

Comment: Are you trying to use the FireFox selenium IDE, or do you have access to a programming language that supports selenium?

Comment: No, I'm using the raw node.js/javascript webdriver with chromedriver.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
var driver = new webdriver.Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();
```

then you will see chrome is opened, DON'T CLOSE IT. then try

```
driver.get('http://www.google.com')
```